# Simplifying trig (sin and cos) expression with identities

Tags: trigonometry

I was working on a trig exercise and I'm not exactly sure how to simplify these expressions. I know the identities are needed to solve the problem but I've never seen angles like these before:

$\cos(\frac{4\pi}{9})$

and

$\sin(\frac{\pi}{55})$

Comment: not enough information. You can not simplify these expressions be themselves,, but maybe together with the rest of you equation.

Comment: $\cos(3\cdot \frac {4\pi}9) = \cos(\frac {4\pi}9)$.  You know what that it.  But $\cos(3\cdot \frac {4\pi}9)= \cos (\frac {4\pi}9+ \frac {4\pi}9+\frac {4\pi}9)$ and you have trig identities to express that in terms of $\cos(\frac {4\pi}9$.  Combine those and solve.

Comment: @fleablood There is a typo in your first expression. On the right hand side should be $4\pi/3$ not $4\pi/9$

Comment: $\sin(\frac{\pi}{55})$ is something I've never seen before... even WolframAlpha nopes out on that one.

Answer (score -1):

These angles are in *radians*

I much prefer degrees to radians, so let's do the conversion! $\frac{4}{9} \cdot pi=80^\circ$. pi radians is equal to 180 degrees.

So we would like to find cos 80 degrees. You can use your calculator to solve that one.

sin(pi/55) is similar.

Hope this helped!

Comment: You can also plug radian measures into trig functions on your calculator, so there's no point to converting. Presumably the question is not "find a good approximation with a calculator" since the OP mentions using identities to simplify expressions.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. But it's a bit easier to use trig identities in degrees, in my opinion.